# How to install C compiler for GCC without Internet connection? (RHEL6)

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

I'm attempting to build GCC from source on a RHEL6 virtual machine, and have run into a Catch 22. That is, I need a C compiler for successful configuration. The solution seems simple enough - execute yum to solve dependencies. However, this virtual machine cannot have an Internet connection.

Does anybody have any sources for a binary or .rpm containing a pre-compiled compiler, simplifying installation? I've searched, but cannot find one. Alternatively, does a RHEL6 command exist to install a pre-compiled version of GCC? If neither are possible, what C compilers might I pursue to resolve this?

For context, here's the message I receive:

```
../gcc-4.7.2/configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/gcc/gcc-build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to compile gcc source code without any C compiler installed on your VM.

If you can transform files from your host to VM, then you have two ways:

1. Compile the source code on your host and copy them to your VM. Use `./configure --prefix=/<path>/<to>/<output>` to specify the output directory. If your VM CPU arch is different from your host, you may want to look at cross compile.
2. Download gcc rpm package from a Redhat's rpm repository mirror. Search it in google and you will get an answer.

But it is always a good idea to use `yum` or `rpm` to install software in RHEL. I have some questions about your problem:

1. Why you don't have gcc installed on your RHEL6? It is installed by default.
2. What VM are you using? The best solution of your problem may be figuring out a way to get network available in your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have Internet access on your VM, you probably won't be able to use the dependency resolving `yum` or `rpm`.  I'll assume you don't want to connect or can't connect the VM to the internet.

From an Internet connected system, you can download a self-contained pre-built version of GCC and the rest of the toolchain here:

- http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/

The IA32 GNU/Linux native compiler is here:

- http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/ia32-gnu-linux
- https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/package10871/public/i686-pc-linux-gnu/ia32-2012.09-62-i686-pc-linux-gnu.bin

You will still need to find a way to get the installer onto your VM.