# I am trying to install C compiler in RHEL6 without internet

Tags: c++, c, linux, nginx, rhel6

I have been trying to install basic softwares needed for making my linux machine into a development env. I got a machine with RHEL6, however it is not connected to the internet. I am able to connect to the lan and ssh to other machines. I tried to install using yum but failed with the following error.

```
[root@******* pcre-8.38]#yum install gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, downloadonly, kabi, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-
              : manager, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI
https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/rhscl/devtoolset-3/epel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/rhscl/devtoolset-3/epel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64. Please verify its path and try again.
```

Prior to this i installed an ngnix web server and tried to do a *make* but that failed with:

```
...
checking windows.h presence... no
checking for windows.h... no
configure: error: You need a C++ compiler for C++ support.
make[1]: *** [/home/gunjaj/software/pcre-8.38/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gunjaj/software/nginx-1.8.1'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS: This question is similar to another question [How to install C compiler for GCC without Internet connection? (RHEL6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853507/how-to-install-c-compiler-for-gcc-without-internet-connection-rhel6)

but i have absolutely no way of getting internet right now.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/156458/how-to-add-an-iso-dvd-of-rhel-to-the-repository-list-under-gnome-for-installing

Comment: If you have RHEL DVD/ISO you mount it to machine and `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: This is a question for Super User or ServerFault, not SO. As SO only becomes relevant once you have a dev env and are actually programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your RHEL machine is configured to download packages from RHEL's official repositories, which are only accessible via the Internet.

If you do not have Internet connectivity, you can reconfigure yum, using the configuration files in /etc/yum.repos.d, to download packages from some local RHEL mirror on your LAN.

Either you have to have Internet connectivity, or you need to configure your server to point to a local mirror of RHEL's official repository. Obviously you cannot install something if that "something" is not to be found anywhere. Sadly, software packages cannot just appear, out of thin air, in order for them to be installed.

The only other option for you is to either; download the relevant RPMs on another machine that does have the necessary connectivity, manually copy them over to this machine, and manually install them using the `rpm` command, and not `yum`; or obtain DVD-based installation media and install the rpms from the installation DVD.